# Bootstrap Radio Form

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I dont understand why my code allows multiple radios to be checked. I only want one to be selected. Do any of you see any errors on my code? Ive looked at a bunch of code examples and I cant see my error. Thank you!

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="createpage.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="showname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Showname</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=“text " id="showname " name="showname "  value=" ">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="foldername " class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Show Folder Name (no spaces)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <input type="text " class="form-control " id="foldername " name="foldername " placeholder=“text" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="showtime" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type in the showtime</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="showtime" name="showtime" placeholder="Weekdays, 1:00-2:00 pm, ET/PT" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <row>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

        <div class="form-group  col-sm-10" align="left">
            <div class="radio">

                <label class="" text-align="left">
                    <input type="radio" value=“/dir/ ">Daytime - /daytime</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio ">
      <label><input type="radio " value="/news ">News - /news</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio ">
      <label><input type="radio " value="/primetime ">Specials - /primetime</label>
    </div>
                <div class="radio ">
      <label><input type="radio " value="/primetime ">Primetime General - /primetime</label>
    </div>
                <div class="radio ">
      <label><input type="radio " value="/primetime/drama ">Primetime Drama - /primetime/drama</label>
    </div>
                <div class="radio ">
      <label><input type="radio " value="/primetime/comedy ">Primetime Comedies - /primetime/comedy</label>
    </div>
        </div><br><br></row>
    <div class="form-group ">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 ">
    <input id="submit " name="submit " type="submit " value="Send " class="btn btn-primary ">
    </div>
    </div>
```

I dont understand why my code allows multiple radios to be checked. I only want one to be selected.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="createpage.php">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="showname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Showname</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=“text " id="showname " name="showname "  value=" ">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="foldername " class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Show Folder Name (no spaces)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <input type="text " class="form-control " id="foldername " name="foldername " placeholder=“text" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="showtime" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type in the showtime</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="showtime" name="showtime" placeholder="Weekdays, 1:00-2:00 pm, ET/PT" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <row>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

        <div class="form-group  col-sm-10" align="left">
            <div class="radio">

                <label class="" text-align="left">
                    <input type="radio" value=“/dir/ ">Daytime - /daytime</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio ">
      <label><input type="radio " value="/news ">News - /news</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio ">
      <label><input type="radio " value="/primetime ">Specials - /primetime</label>
    </div>
                <div class="radio ">
      <label><input type="radio " value="/primetime ">Primetime General - /primetime</label>
    </div>
                <div class="radio ">
      <label><input type="radio " value="/primetime/drama ">Primetime Drama - /primetime/drama</label>
    </div>
                <div class="radio ">
      <label><input type="radio " value="/primetime/comedy ">Primetime Comedies - /primetime/comedy</label>
    </div>
        </div><br><br></row>
    <div class="form-group ">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 ">
    <input id="submit " name="submit " type="submit " value="Send " class="btn btn-primary ">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your radios must have the same "name" attribute in order to work as mutually-exclusive. Add a name attribute to your radios and give it the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is you have different names and that means that we till
>   html that each different name we can access at the same time to fix
>   that you need to give each group same name different values for
>   example:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

> ِAs you see names are the same but values are different.

(I add names and name first as `radioGroup1` and the second as `radioGroup2`)
Here is your code :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="createpage.php">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="showname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Showname</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=“text" id="showname" name="showname"  value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="foldername" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Show Folder Name (no spaces)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foldername" name="foldername" placeholder=“text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="showtime" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type in the showtime</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="showtime" name="showtime" placeholder="Weekdays, 1:00-2:00 pm, ET/PT" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<row>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="form-group  col-sm-10" align="left">
        <div class="radio">
            <label class="" text-align="left" ><input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" value=“/dir/">Daytime - /daytime</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" value="/news">News - /news</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" value="/primetime">Specials - /primetime</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" value="/primetime">Primetime General - /primetime</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" value="/primetime/drama">Primetime Drama - /primetime/drama</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" value="/primetime/comedy">Primetime Comedies - /primetime/comedy</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
</row>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>
I dont understand why my code allows multiple radios to be checked. I only want one to be selected.
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="createpage.php">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="showname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Showname</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=“text" id="showname" name="showname"  value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="foldername" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Show Folder Name (no spaces)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foldername" name="foldername" placeholder=“text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="showtime" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type in the showtime</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="showtime" name="showtime" placeholder="Weekdays, 1:00-2:00 pm, ET/PT" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<row>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="form-group  col-sm-10" align="left">
        <div class="radio">
            <label class="" text-align="left" ><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" value=“/dir/">Daytime - /daytime</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" value="/news">News - /news</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" value="/primetime">Specials - /primetime</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" value="/primetime">Primetime General - /primetime</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" value="/primetime/drama">Primetime Drama - /primetime/drama</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" value="/primetime/comedy">Primetime Comedies - /primetime/comedy</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
</row>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Now is working, Let me know if you have any question.**

Comment: Thanks for chose my answer as the best, Also If you can vote up too please. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your radio inputs must have the same `name` attribute in order for the browser to know what group they belong too. Only one radio input can be selected in a group of radio inputs with the same name.

Here is an example without `labels`

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="radio1" />
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="radio2" />
```

Also, all of your inputs should have a `name`. Without them, nothing will be passed to the server.